# Ruby: Assert_raise alternative?

Tags: ruby

I'm working out Ruby Kons and  I stopped in about_Hashes. It took me a bit to understand what asserts are and how they work and I think I get it but suddenly `assert_raise` appears! I'm confused and now even google can explain me clearly how does it works. So basically there is my question:

Does this piece of code:

```
hash = { :one => "uno" }
assert_raise(KeyError) do
  hash.fetch(:doesnt_exist)
end
```

Equal this piece of code:

```
hash = {:one => "uno"}
begin 
  hash.fetch(:doesnt_exist)
rescue Exception => exp
  exp.message
end
```

Am I correct?

Comment: [`assert_raise`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_raise) is part of `Test::Unit`. I'm sure someone will explain it in more detail and how it is used in Ruby-Koans but for the moment, just know it is part of Ruby's Unit Testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close - `assert_raise` in your case would look more like this:

```
hash = {:one => "uno"}
begin 
  hash.fetch(:doesnt_exist)
rescue KeyError
  # Test passes if this happens
rescue Exception
  # Test fails if any other exception is raised, must be KeyError
end
# Test fails if no exception is raised
```

The only difference is that it makes sure the exception caught is the one that you're asserting.

`assert_raise` is part of `Test::Unit`. It says that the block of code that follows should raise an exception. You got pretty close with your approximation with `begin` and `rescue`, so it looks like you understand it fundamentally.